# How do I insert a character every 2 spaces in a string?

Tags: sql, string, db2-400

I have a table with a 50 CHAR column, with a content like

```
AABB
AA
CCXXDD
```

It's a string used like an array of 25 elements CHAR 2.

I need to insert a comma every 2 characters

```
AA,BB
AA
CC,XX,DD
```

It there a system function or I need to create one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do a regex replacement here:

```sql
SELECT col, RTRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '(..)', '\1,'), ',') AS col_out
FROM yourTable;
```

The above logic inserts a comma after every two characters.  For inputs having an even number of characters, this leaves an unwanted dangling comma on the right, which we remove using `RTRIM()`.